# Reload a page when clicking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, post, checkbox

I need to reload a page when a check box is check/unchecked and also store this value to a variable.

$variable = "checked" if the check box is checked
$variable = "unchecked" if the check box is unchecked

I am noob on Java Script, so can anyone show an exemple? Is it possible to use html instead?

Comment: Are you using pure js or angular jquery? because you need to create an event listner on click on that checkbox.

Comment: I actually don't know. What is the difference between them? Let's assume it is pure.

Comment: jquery and angular are different javascript frameworks.

Comment: do you want to pass the variable to the reloaded page?

Comment: Why do you need to keep that as a variable on the server. you realise that a regular variable will be destroyed when the query is complete.

Comment: Yes I do want to pass the variable to the reloaded page. I need to keep track of checked/unchecked value to change my page according to this value.

Comment: building a fiddle and editing your question might help: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Instead of a variable, why not just pull the information directly from the element?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do that. That is my question, how to extract the information from the element after page is reloaded?